# I can't figure out how to fix error NullPointerException

Tags: java

I think that `smallIndex`, `index`, and `temp` all have values, so Im not sure why I am getting the error. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? The error message is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class LinkedList
{
  public class LinkedListNode
  {
     public int info;
     public LinkedListNode next;
     public LinkedListNode back;

     public LinkedListNode()
     {
        info = 0;
        next = null;
        back = null;
     }
     public LinkedListNode(int item)
     {
        info = item;
        next = null;
        back = null;
     }
     public void displayInfo()
     {
        System.out.print(info + " ");
     }
  }
  protected int count;
  protected LinkedListNode first;
  protected LinkedListNode last;

  public LinkedList()
  {
     first = null;
     last = null;
     count = 0;
  }
  public void initializeList()
  {
     first = null;
     last = null;
     count = 0;
  }
  public boolean isEmpty()
  {
     return (first == null);
  }
  public int length()
  {
     return count;
  }
  public void print()
  {
     LinkedListNode current = first;
     while (current != null)
     {
        current.displayInfo();
        current = current.next;
     }
  }
  public void insertNode(int insertItem)
  {
     LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(insertItem);
     if (isEmpty())
     {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        count++;
     }
     else
     {
        last.next = newNode;
        newNode.back = last;
     }
     last = newNode;
  }
  public LinkedListNode partition(LinkedList list,
  LinkedListNode first, LinkedListNode last)
  {
     LinkedListNode smallIndex = first;
     LinkedListNode index = smallIndex.next;
     LinkedListNode temp = new LinkedListNode();
     int pivot = first.info;

     while (index != last.next)
     {
        if((index.info) < pivot)
        {
           smallIndex = smallIndex.next;
           temp.info = index.info;
           index.info = smallIndex.info;
           smallIndex.info = temp.info;
        }
        index = index.next;
     }
     temp.info = first.info;
     first.info = smallIndex.info;
     smallIndex.info = temp.info;
     System.out.print("The list after QuickSort is: "); 
     list.print();
     System.out.print("\n");
     return smallIndex;
  }
  public void recQuickSort(LinkedList list, LinkedListNode first,
  LinkedListNode last)
  {
     while(first != last)
     {
        LinkedListNode pivotLocation = partition(list, first, last);
        recQuickSort(list, first, pivotLocation.back);
        recQuickSort(list, pivotLocation.next, last);
     }
  }
  public void quickSortLinkedList(LinkedList list)
  {
     recQuickSort(list, list.first, list.last);
  }

}



import java.util.*;

public class testLinkedListQuickSort
{
  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     LinkedList linkedlist = new LinkedList();
     int num;

     System.out.println("Enter numbers to add to linked list:");
     num = console.nextInt();
     while (num != 0)
     {
        linkedlist.insertNode(num);
        num = console.nextInt();
     }
     linkedlist.quickSortLinkedList(linkedlist);
     linkedlist.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: post the stack trace.

Comment: And the exact code that you run--which methods are being called in which order.

Comment: in which line you are getting exception ?

Comment: The list after QuickSort is: 
The list after QuickSort is: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at LinkedList.partition(LinkedList.java:83)
 at LinkedList.recQuickSort(LinkedList.java:107)
 at LinkedList.recQuickSort(LinkedList.java:108)
 at LinkedList.recQuickSort(LinkedList.java:108)
 at LinkedList.quickSortLinkedList(LinkedList.java:114)
 at testLinkedListQuickSort.main(testLinkedListQuickSort.java:19)

Comment: OT: I can't imagine how can you use a quicksort (or another kind of sort) in a linked list w/o thinking on performance. Is that what your professor assigned you?

Comment: The first line where the error occurs is this: while (index != last.next)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes my professor assigned this.

Comment: @wolne, you should edit your full stacktrace into your question.  When people are asking for you to clarify something, usually they are also asking you to modify your question as well.  This helps others because then they don't have to dig through dozens of comments to get all the information they need to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comments: you call partition with

```
recQuickSort(list, first, pivotLocation.back);
```

Do if `pivotLocation.back` is `null` then the partition method is called with `last == null` which leads to your NPE.

Answer (score 0):

In your `partition()` method, you're not doing much checking for `null` values.  For instance, if `smallIndex`, `index`, `temp`, or `last` are `null`, then that will blow up.  There's also `first`, which if it's `null`, would cause the NPE.

It's a good idea to ensure that what you're being passed in the recursive call isn't an empty node.  I don't see many checks for that.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` occurs when you are trying to access a reference **where there is no value.**

Or when calling the instance method of a null object and accessing or modifying the field of a null object.

Or when you pass null to a method which expects a real value. It means to say that null object is used illegally.

I didnt looked at your code much but to resolve this, **determine which Object instance is null and causing the problem.** You will need to modify your code in order to add proper null check validations